# Is it possible to read function closure via V8 addon?

Tags: c++, closures, v8, node-gyp, embedded-v8

I want to write a Node.js V8 addon in C++ that will give me access to functions closures.

Something like this:

```
const myAddon = require('./build/Release/addon');

const counter = (() => {
  let i = 0;
  return () => ++i;
})();

counter(); // 1
counter(); // 2

const closure = myAddon(counter);
console.log(closure.i); // prints "3"
```

Is it possible? Where this information stored on the [V8 engine](http://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/index.html)?

Comment: You want a handle to a variable lexically scoped within a function from outside the function by using a handle to the function?  That is not possible.  If you want access to it, then why not close it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. And that's a feature. It allows the engine to optimise local variables in various ways, including eliminating them entirely. Without that ability, JavaScript programs would run substantially slower than they already do. The best you can get is what the debugger interface provides, and that's only a best effort attempt to reconstruct as much information as is still possible. Depending on how a function got optimised it may be incomplete or even wrong.

Also, closures are the only way in JavaScript to express proper encapsulation. Such a library would break that property.